# Chromedriver won't launch headlessly with Protractor tests (error 199)

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor, jenkins-pipeline

**EDIT**: Not Jenkins-specific. I'm getting the same error when simply launching the tests from command line.
I want to run Protractor tests in Jenkins, using a specific Chromedriver , that is stored in my project.
Here is my config file:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://monsite:9095/wd/hub',

    // Basically I put everything that sounds like Chrome.
    chromeOnly: true,
    // directConnect: true, // will uncomment it later...
    chromeDriver: '../node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 999999
    },

    specs: ['demo.js'],

    baseUrl: 'http://monsite:3000'
};
```

Works like a charm in my IDE, but when I run the tests from Jenkins Pipeline, Jenkins tries to use his own Chromedriver, even if I unsinstall the Chromedriver plugin.
This error message appears:

```
[15:58:27] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:58:27] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://monsite.ovh.net:9095/wd/hub
[15:59:27] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 3.13.0-105-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.34 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'monsite.ovh.net', ip: '51.255.171.51', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-105-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
[15:59:27] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 3.13.0-105-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.34 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'monsite.ovh.net', ip: '51.255.171.51', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-105-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at WebDriverError (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
    at createDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:167:33)
    at Builder.build (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:623:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.ts:60:29)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[15:59:27] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 199
Finished: FAILURE
```

This occurs in the stage when I run:

```
sh 'sudo protractor tests/src/conf-demo.js'
```

I've updated the configuration of Jenkins Selenium Grid plugin to match what I've set in the Protractor conf file.
I've tried using `directConnect: true` in my Protractor conf file, but I get quite the same error:

```
+ sudo protractor tests/src/conf-demo.js
[16:56:35] W/driverProviders - Using driver provider directConnect, but also found extra driver provider parameter(s): seleniumAddress
[16:56:35] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:56:35] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:56:36] E/launcher - Server terminated early with status 1
[16:56:36] E/launcher - Error: Server terminated early with status 1
    at Error (native)
    at earlyTermination.catch.e (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:252:52)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.ts:90:25)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[16:56:36] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 199
Finished: FAILURE
```

Tools versions...

```
[11:13:44] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.4.0 [last]
[11:13:44] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.24 [last]
[11:13:44] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.16.1 [last]
[11:13:44] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[11:13:44] I/status - appium is not present
```

My Google Chrome version was 55, upgraded it to 58, same behavior.

What the *frog* am I missing? Help will be unoverstatably appreciated.

Comment: Where you run your jenkins? Be aware that for starting chrome you need  some X Window. Otherwise you need to start a headless Browser

Comment: Hello @Torsten, I run my Jenkins on a VPS. I use the Selenium Grid plugin. In the Jenkins "Global tool configuration" page, I have set up XVFB. Other jobs involving headless browsers are working just fine on the same Jenkins instance (I just launched one, which went well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added something in my Protractor configuration file that solved the problem:

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        // NEW
        'chromeOptions': {
            args: ["--headless", 'no-sandbox', "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800x600"]
        }
    },
```

The tests launch. They get another error (they dont plug to the Xvfb). But this one is [another story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150844/headless-protractor-tests-dont-plug-on-xvfb)...