# Headless protractor tests don't plug on Xvfb

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, protractor, xvfb

I'm trying to run Protractor tests both in command line and with Jenkins. Both fail with the same error.

### Command line

- I opened a prompt and launched `webdriver-manager start`
- In another prompt, I launched `Xvfb :42 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &`
- In a third one, I eventually launched `protractor myconf.js`

### Jenkins

- In my build, I checked "Start Xvfb before the build, and shut it down after.".
- I run the tests in a shell script.

  sh 'sudo webdriver-manager clean'
  sh 'sudo webdriver-manager update'
  sh 'xvfb-run webdriver-manager start --seleniumPort 9094 &'
  checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'tests']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'myprettycredentials', url: 'myprettyproject.git']]])
     sh 'sudo sudo chmod -R a+rwx tests'
     sh 'sudo killall Xvfb'
     sh 'export DISPLAY=:43'
     sh 'sudo Xvfb :43 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &'
     wrap([$class: 'Xvfb']) {
        sh 'sudo protractor tests/src/conf-demo.js --troubleshoot'
     }

**In both cases**, I get this error.

```
Failed: unknown error: an X display is required for keycode conversions,
consider using Xvfb
```

Why won't my tests plug on the Xvfb I started for them so zealously? Thanks for your help.

Comment: did u use the command    "export DISPLAY=:42" ?

Comment: Yes I did. Doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I finally managed to run my Protractor tests headlessly using

```
xvfb-run -a webdriver-manager start --seleniumPort 9094 &
protractor myconf.js
```

Where `-a` chooses any free display, and `&` makes the task run in background.

Answer (score 0):

Great to hear you resolve your issue.

Another alternative would be to create a gulp task and use the [gulp-angular-protractor](https://github.com/rochejul/gulp-angular-protractor) extension. I think is easier to configure and run.

And install the xvfb plugin to use it on the configuration on your job.

Good Luck !